# Where is the best place to ask about kde pim scripts

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm working on a bare bones bash/yad script to pop up an info box when a KDE korganizer event reminder is triggered.

I'm looking for help on how to code the message text to get colors, etc. (HTML subset?) and for an easy way to test the script in korganizer.  (details reserved for a post in the right forum)

Which forum suits this best?

(I tried to use the official and unofficial kde forums.  Their captchas are almost impossible to get right and then, support is very random.  It's many orders of magnitude better here!)

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Super User](http://superuser.com) has a [pretty good roster](https://superuser.com/tags/kde/topusers) of KDE Enthusiasts, but I think [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) would connect you to the [best audience](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/kde/topusers) for your particular question.

A lot of Linux/Unix questions could technically overlap between the sites, but if you're looking to do something programmatically, or really exploring the technical innards of something, Unix & Linux is probably your best bet.

Ask Ubuntu also has some [great folks that could help you](https://askubuntu.com/tags/kubuntu/topusers), but your question really isn't in the context that they're established to serve.

Once you've determined that a question could be on topic in several places by checking the respective 'What can I ask here?' sections of the FAQs, the tag info / stat pages are a great way to narrow down your decision. Unfortunately, people often don't discover them for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know "where the KDE ones are" ;)  . It may just be me, but it sees like most people who know what they're doing don't use KDE and it's hard to find help.  I've been using it since Mandrake 9.1 and I'm hooked on it.  Seems much more user friendly than other things I've tried.